# count of sold product in specific day count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I m stuck in that problem.

```
CustomerId | EmployeeID | OrderDate| 
1              2          2013-01-01  
2              2          2013-01-01
2              2          2013-01-02
3              1          2013-02-14
3              2          2013-01-02
4              2          2013-01-03
5              2          2013-01-04
6              2          2013-01-06  
7              2          2013-01-05
```

I dont know how to ask but I hope I will do my best.

I want to learn which Employe sold how many product in 3 days
Forexample: EmployeID 2 sold some product in

```
 2013-01-01,2013-01-01 = 1. day (2 sells)
 2013-01-02 = 2.day (2 sell)
 2013-01-03 = 3.day (1 sell)
```

So we can see in 3 days Employe sold 5 products. And

```
 2013-01-04 = 1.day (1 sell)
 2013-01-05 = 2.day (1 sell)
 2013-01-06 = 3.day (1 sell)
```

Employe sold 3 more in another 3 days. So output table will look like

```
EmployeID | SoldProductIn3Days|
  2            5
  2            3
```

How can I query this in t-sql?

Comment: Which 3 days? What about `EmployeeID` = 1?

Comment: any 3 days, EmployeID=1 only sold in 2013-02-14 so its just 1 day. I just care count of date which is equal 3.

Comment: Do these 3 days need to be consecutive?

Comment: yes becouse I think we can only understand that days count number is 3.

Comment: Your requirements are still unclear. Try explaining in more detail step-by-step.

Comment: Ok, Lets say I want to give 100$ to Employees which sold more than 4 products in 3 days. How can I query this?

Comment: So basically, for any employee you need the maximum products sold in **any** 3 days he was selling something, right?

Comment: yes sir. exactly it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have changed the answer to meet the requirements of the comments.

```
DECLARE @MySales AS TABLE
(
 CustomerID INT
,EmployeeID INT
,OrderDate DATE
);

WITH    Sales
      AS ( SELECT OrderDate
               ,EmployeeID
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS RowNum
            FROM @MySales),
    SalesCalc
      AS ( SELECT OrderDate
               ,EmployeeID
               ,CONVERT(INT, Rownum / 3.01) AS MyGrouping
            FROM Sales)
SELECT EmployeeID, MyGrouping, COUNT(*)
    FROM SalesCalc
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, MyGrouping
```

I have used table variable to simulate your table, but just take my table variable out and place your table in there. This should do the trick. When I divide RowNumber by 3.1 it generates a 0,0,0 for first 3 days than 1,1,1 for next 3 days and so on, in the end everything is group and counted.

Comment: Thanks for answer but, no my question is not about this.

Comment: then you clarify your question on what you need exactly?

Comment: I already did, pls read comments on my question you will get it.  for any employee I need the maximum products sold in any 3 days he was selling something

Comment: Ok this should be what you are asking for